# C++: Compare return value of C function to NULL or nullptr?

Tags: c++, null, nullptr

I'm coding in C++, and using a C function that returns NULL in case of a failure. What would be the correct think to do, compare its return value to NULL or nullptr?

```
if ((CreateEventEx(myEventHandleHere) == NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
if ((CreateEventEx(myEventHandleHere) == nullptr)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use nullptr - have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/nullptr

Comment: If the function returns `NULL` in case of failure, you should compare its return value to `NULL`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's a pity that `NULL` and `nullptr` are totally identical in every way in this respect, then.

Comment: Why not avoid the issue and write `if (!CreateEventEx(myEventHandleHere))` it even kinda reads in English

Answer (score 5):

The [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) in appendix `C.4` *C Standard library* which is non-normative says:

> The macro NULL, defined in any of <clocale>, <cstddef>, <cstdio>,
>   <cstdlib>, <cstring>, <ctime>, or <cwchar>, is an
>   implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International
>   Standard (18.2).

the respective normative sections agree for example `18.2` says:

> The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant
>   in this International Standard (4.10).194

which would mean if you are using the those particular headers `NULL` should be compatible with `nullptr` and then I would just use `nullptr`.

In appendix `D` which covers compatibility does not seem to make a similar statement for `.h` header files, so although we would expect that `NULL` and `nullptr` should be compatible *null pointer constants* and we would be surprised if they were not from the standard point of view it seems at minimum to be underspecified. Which leaves us with a dilemma, from a practical perspective we are pretty sure they are compatible but we don't have enough information from the standard to prove it.

So I would use `NULL` as defined by the specific header file you are using or we can use `!= 0` since fortunately both C99 and C++11 tell us that `0` is a *null pointer constant*.

From C99 section `6.3.2.3` *Pointers*:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.55) If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.

and:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined

and C++ section `4.10` *Pointer conversions* tells us:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero
>   or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be
>   converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of
>   that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object
>   pointer or function pointer type.[...]

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly and totally equivalent, so use `nullptr` because `NULL` is a primitive C-ism that has no reason to live anymore.

But in the case of CreateEventEx you have the hilarious bonus of not all invalid `HANDLE`s being `nullptr`, some of them are `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead. So neither is really "safe" in the case of `HANDLE`. You need to check exactly what CreateEventEx returns on failure.

Comment: I agree with you morally but the standard only says it is equivalent for for the `<clocale>, <cstddef>, <cstdio>, <cstdlib>, <cstring>, <ctime>, or <cwchar>` or at least I can't find a statement that would apply to `.h` files. At best it seems ambiguous.

Comment: It is equivalent by definition. The file containing the function prototype is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NULL` since that is what C uses (also, `nullptr` is new in C++11, so if you are not using C++11 then you have to use `NULL`).  On the other hand, you could simply not check for either value explicitly, do an implicit comparison instead, let the compiler check for `!= 0` for you:

```
if (CreateEventEx(myEventHandleHere))
{
    ...
}
```

You should assign the value to a variable so you can free it later (if that is what the C API requires):

```
TypeName event = CreateEventEx(myEventHandleHere);
if (event)
{
    ...
    free event when done...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why it matters if the function returns NULL. That is an implementation detail. There are many old C++ functions which return NULL. And many new functions will return `nullptr`. So, if you decide to switch from `NULL` to `nullptr` for null pointer values in your *own* code, then you should be consistent about that, regardless of whether the function happens to originally written as C. When it is compiled as C++, it becomes a C++ function.

However. In this case, the return type is a `HANDLE`. The fact that `HANDLE` is actually a typedef for a `void*` is an implementation detail. The WinAPI documentation says that when a `HANDLE` is invalid, it is comparable to `NULL`. In this case, I would suggest you go with the WinAPI documentation, and use `NULL`. If the WinAPI didn't use typedefs, and just documented all its functions as returning `void*`, then I would use `nullptr`, if you use `nullptr` in the rest of your C++ code.