# Can the NULL macro actually be a nullptr?

Tags: c++, null, language-lawyer, nullptr

According to the draft of the standard N4713 (7.11/1):

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (5.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

and 21.2.3/2:

> The macro `NULL` is an implementation-defined null pointer constant.

follow that `NULL` can be defined as `nullptr`. Same is mentioned on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL):

```
#define NULL 0
//since C++11
#define NULL nullptr
```

At the same time "Additive operators" clause says (8.5.6/7):

> If the value `0` is added to or subtracted from a null pointer value, the result is a null pointer value. If two null
>   pointer values are subtracted, the result compares equal to the value `0` converted to the type `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Hence the following code should be valid:

```
0 + nullptr; 
nullptr - nullptr;
```

but because of the lack of +/- operators for `std::nullptr_t` the [code is invalid](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L73ROVmycwIWMJYw).

Is there something that I didn't take into account or `NULL` macro can't be actually defined as `nullptr`?

Comment: yes it can. [[[[[[[[[[

Comment: "Is there something that I didn't take into account", yes, that you can add 0 to literal 0.

Comment: Null pointer *value* and null pointer *constant* are two very different things.

Comment: @n.m: The distinction between *pointer*, `nullptr_t` and *literal 0* is important, yes. But considering "or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t", are you maintaining that a prvalue isn't a value? That's absurd.

Comment: Just to drive that home, the standard's *definition* is "A null pointer constant is ... a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t" (the dots are the case of literal, which it also can be).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is a *value*, but it is not a "null pointer value."

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Of course it's a value, of type `std::nullptr_t`, which is not a pointer type, so there's no basis for calling it a "null pointer value" (it's not a pointer value at all). At any rate, the "Additive operators" clause  lists types that may participate in additive operators, and `std::nullptr_t` is not one of those, so `std::nullptr - std::nullptr` is invalid whether you call `std::nullptr` "a null pointer value" or not.

Comment: Windows says no. :(

Comment: Related [C++: Compare return value of C function to NULL or nullptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25650592/1708801)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

While `nullptr` is a null pointer *constant*, it is not a null pointer *value*. The latter is a value of some pointer type, which `std::nullptr_t` is not.

Reference:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (5.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. **A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type** and is
>   distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called
>   a null pointer conversion. [...]

7.11/1 in N4659, emphasize mine

So `NULL` can indeed be `nullptr` without providing the arithmetic operators.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's a value alright, but the standard explicitly speaks of null pointer values as values of pointers. `nullptr` is not a pointer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - No, he deserves an up-vote because the standard text treats *null pointer value* as a term, and not just *value*. And if you want to dredge up past encounters, don't you go then blaming others for getting personal.

Comment: Any constant is a value. There just isn't any requirement that `nullptr` should support addition. However, literal `0` does support addition, and the standard describes the result of adding compile time 0 to `0`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If I'm wrong, could you please give me a better explanation than *"A constant is a value"*? A lot of things are values in C++, how that's relevant to the question whether `nullptr` is a null pointer value is not clear to me yet.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - Perhaps [\[basic.compound\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3), to better drive that point home?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I think [S.M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48904174/464581) is good. Also my own in comments to question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sorry, but I fail to see how *"`nullptr` itself is not a pointer value nor pointer. Thus arithmetic operations are not applicable to `nullptr`"* is right if *"it is not a null pointer value"* is wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the link, but I think that is more relevant for proving that a pointer can have a null pointer value, not so much for defining what that actually is.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf C++17 7.11/1 "A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (5.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. A
null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is
distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called
a *null pointer conversion.*" This seems to pretty clearly indicate that `nullptr` (or any other prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`) is *not* a "null pointer value."

Comment: @Angew: Thanks, but that was already cited by the OP. It says a nullpointer is, among other things a prvalue of type `std::nullptr`. That it is a prvalue supports that it is a value.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Whether or not it's a value is out of the question, but where does it say it's a null pointer value?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's exactly the paragraph I already do cite, unless something has changed there between N4659 and C++17. I haven't bought the latter, so if relevant, thanks for pointing out the difference.

Comment: I need new eyes. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 9):

`nullptr` is a null pointer literal, and although the result of converting `nullptr` to a pointer type is the null pointer value, `nullptr` itself isn't of a pointer type, but of type `std::nullptr_t`. The arithmetic works if you do convert the `nullptr` to a pointer type:

```
0 + (int*)nullptr; 
(int*)nullptr - (int*)nullptr;
```

---

> Can the NULL macro actually be a nullptr?

Yes, because `nullptr` is a null pointer literal.

Note that prior to C++11, the all of the null pointer literals in C++ happened to also be integer literals, so this bad code: `char c = NULL;` used to work in practice. If `NULL` is defined as `nullptr`, that code no longer works.

Answer (score 6):

The keyword `nullptr` denotes the pointer literal. It is a `prvalue` of type `std::nullptr_t`. There exist implicit conversions from `nullptr` to null pointer value of any pointer type and any pointer to member type.
`nullptr` itself is not a pointer value nor pointer. Thus arithmetic operations are not applicable to `nullptr`.

Comment: so 8.5.6/7 does not apply to `nullptr` because it is not a null pointer value? (deleted this comment after reading Baums answer and repostet after reading the discussion below that answer ;)

Comment: If `nullptr` is of `std::nullptr_t` type, and not of a pointer type, how is it a pointer literal? You may want to think about rephrasing a bit to be more accurate.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, you are correct. A `prvalue` (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an `xvalue`. [Example: The result of calling a function whose return type is not a reference is a `prvalue`] - copied from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Comment: @StoryTeller `NULL` is implementation-defined null pointer constant.
`nullptr_t` is the type of the null pointer literal `nullptr`, like `char` is the type of char literal `'a'`, or `const char const *` is the type of the string literal `"abc"`.

Comment: I don't think you got what I was aiming for. Literals are **typed** values. Since `nullptr_t` is not a pointer type, `nullptr` can't be a pointer literal.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think the standard could be clearer about this: *"The **pointer literal** is the keyword nullptr.
It is a prvalue of type std​::​nullptr_­t.
[ Note: std​::​nullptr_­t is a distinct type that **is neither a pointer type** nor ..."* Clearly not being a pointer type does not prevent `nullptr` from being a pointer literal.

Comment: @user2079303 - Well, so much for consistency with other prvalue literals. It's not of a "pointer type", but it's a "pointer literal"!? WTF.

Answer (score 6):

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a completely-defined object type and the other shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type.
>
> For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:
> (2.1) both operands have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type; or
> (2.2) both operands are pointers to cv-qualified or cv-unqualified versions of the same completely-defined object type; or
> (2.3) the left operand is a pointer to a completely-defined object type and the right operand has integral or unscoped enumeration type.

`std::nullptr_t` is none of those, hence `std::nullptr` cannot participate in additive operations.

Note that not even all pointer values can participate. For example, function pointer values and void pointer values cannot, even though either can be a null pointer value.